# Select and return only matching value(s) from JSON field

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to find a way to return matching role(s) for the query below but not sure if it is possible at all. I looked around but couldn't find anything.

```
SELECT
/* here return either 'user' or 'user,admin' */
FROM users
WHERE
id = 'xyz' AND
roles::jsonb ?| array['user','admin'];
```

Field (`json` type) in DB and what query result should look like

```
roles: ["manager"]      -> should return nothing
roles: ["user"]         -> should return 'user'
roles: ["admin"]        -> should return 'admin'
roles: ["user","admin"] -> should return 'user,admin'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve the desired result is to ***[`jsonb_array_elements_text`](https://www.sqliz.com/postgresql-ref/jsonb_array_elements_text/)*** to remove the nesting from the `json` array and after that filter the roles using a where clause. Something like:

```sql
WITH matched_roles AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        jsonb_array_elements_text(roles) AS role
    FROM
        users
    WHERE
        id = 'xyz' AND
        roles::jsonb ?| array['user', 'admin']
)
SELECT
    string_agg(role, ',') AS matched_roles
FROM
    matched_roles;
```

***[CODE DEMO](https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3zsadtmdw)***

Comment: That's great. Thank you. Just needed to use `json_array_elements_text` instead as the other function was required to be added.